# How to match the number of underscores with the number of letters in an input list in Python

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to programming and have set myself the task of generating a Hangman game on Python. The code that I have so far is at the bottom of this post for reference: it's almost complete, but I have a very annoying problem when I try to print the same number of underscores as there are letters in the word to be guessed. I don't know why, but, despite Python clearly understanding that, when I give

```
word = ['n','i','g','h','t']
```

as my input word in the kernel, it knows that "night" is the word that needs guessing, it prints a number of underscores corresponding to the number of letters in the default list I've assigned to the variable 'word', which is "whatever" i.e. 8 underscores rather than 5. I know it knows "night" is the correct word because I can guess it and this is the end result:

```
In [227]: attempt(word,'n')
>>> n i g h t _ _ _
>>> a b c d e f - - - j k l m - o p q r s - u v - x y z
```

which leaves three blank underscores at the end. Does anyone have any idea how to remove these underscores without affecting the rest of the programme?

Here's the code:

```
space,alphabet=' ',['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

word = ['w','h','a','t','e','v','e','r']
word_blanks = ['_' for letter in word]

def attempt(word,inp1=''):
    if inp1 in word:
        indeces=[i for i,val in enumerate(word) if val==inp1]
        for i in indeces:
            word_blanks[i]=inp1
    if inp1 in alphabet:
        loc=alphabet.index(inp1)
        alphabet[loc]='-'
    print space.join(word_blanks)
    print space.join(alphabet)
```

I hope this is all clear and comes out correctly. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The starting length of `word_blanks` is 8, and you never reset it,  so you only overwrite certain positions in it, and the length stays 8. Try using a word longer than 8 characters for `word.` you will get an `IndexError` if you guess a letter after position 7, because it will try to change `word_blanks[8]`

You need to generate a new version of `word_blanks` every time you get a new word for this code to work.